# django rest framework - POST request causes 400 status code

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-rest-framework, serialization, django-serializer

I am trying to perform a POST request to create an article and I am getting this error `Request failed with status code 400 Bad Request: /api/articles/create/`.

An article needs 3 attributes to be created:
(1) title
(2) body
(3) author (the current user)

The router works fine since the POST request goes into the `post` method of the `ArticleCreateView` class. But I'm guessing that `serializer.is_valid()` is returning `False` for some reason. 
Also `print(request.data)` returns `{'title': 'hello', 'body': 'stuff'}`

Another mystery about Django is, how does the serializer know if I want to get, create or update something? In all the examples I've seen, the serializer magically seems to know this.

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author = self.context['request'].user
        title = validated_data.get('title')
        body = validated_data.get('body')
        return Article.objects.create(author=author, title=title, body=body)


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: can you add `Article` model?

Comment: @JPG I have added it now

Comment: add your  AUTH_USER_MODEL too

Comment: @nishant the AUTH_USER_MODEL is something builtin to Django I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your serializer, the validation process needs **`author`** details, which is not passing through POST payload.
So, make the **`author`** field in the serializer a not required field by adding **`required=False`** or use a **`ReadOnlyField()`** or specify **`read_only_fields`** in Meta class. Also pass context data as [@nishant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7065051/nishant) mentioned

```
# views.py
class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data, context={"request": request}) # change here 
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
# serializer.py
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('author',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author = self.context['request'].user
        title = validated_data.get('title')
        body = validated_data.get('body')
        return Article.objects.create(author=author, title=title, body=body)
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable "POST /api/articles/create/ HTTP/1.1" 500`

Comment: I have added it

Comment: @Senyokbalgul I've updated the serializer.py. Try now

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request':request})
```

Comment: I already tried this. And it is not mandatory to specify the `context` since it is passed into the serializer implicitly.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul can you add your AUTH_USER_MODEL too

Comment: the AUTH_USER_MODEL is something builtin to Django I think

Comment: Okay so you are using builtin model

Comment: it is `from django.conf import settings` and then `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: @Senyokbalgul is your createapiview working correctly